# Laravel JWT API token handling

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I started with an API inside Laravel with the JWT package, another Laravel frontend installation should be able to login to this Laravel API, but im not really sure how to handle this the right way.

My setup is like this:

Laravel API -> receives POST login -> returns a token and a user model -> Laravel frontend receives this data

But then what? How would I 'auth' the right way inside the Laravel frontend part?

Just set my own sessions and check that way? Any suggestions would be nice! :)

Comment: If you're using token based login, then setting sessions wouldn't work I don't think?

Comment: The problem is that I am not sure how to handle the user inside the frontend. The frontend is posting a email and password to the API, the API returns a token and a user.

Comment: Are you using middleware to check for a token?

Comment: In the frontend? No, because I am not sure what middleware I should use there.

The API does contain the middleware, yes.

Comment: Are you using your API inside another framework like Ionic or Angular? Is there a reason for using the API?

Comment: Not yet, but that will be the case later on.

For now its:

DB -> API -> Frontend website

Comment: https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs - this may help

Comment: Curious if you figured this out. I'm attempting the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First you authenticate with the Laravel API, performing the POST request as you mentioned. This should provide you your JWT or `access_token`, along with a refresh token.

You then append this token to your requests in the `Authorization` header.

So the key is `Authorization` and the value will be `Bearer <access_token>`.

Finally your routes must have the correct middleware to require a valid token, for example the auth middleware.